# How to get a form data in flask route

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I have a login route which a user can login to the account. I want to get the form data of that login route from another route. But it always fails.

```
@app.route('/attendance', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def attendance():
    O_id = request.form.get('O_id')
    print('Welcome', O_id)
    emp_nums = {'1000': 'DEV', '1001': 'ANA'}
    value = emp_nums.get(O_id,"")
    print('team is',value)

    userDetails = Employee_data.query.filter_by(team = value).all()
    return render_template('take_attendance.html', userDetails=userDetails)
```

I use this simple HTML form

```
 <form action="" method="POST" margin="center">
      <label>ID</label>
      <input type="text" name="U_id" value 
      {{request.form.U_id}}">

      <label>Password</label>
      <input type="password" na`enter code here`me="password" value="{{request.form.password}}">

      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
      </form>
```

The Employee_data model is

```
class Employee_data(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    O_id= db.Column(db.String(20), unique=True, nullable=False)
    team = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)
    name = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    location = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)

def __repr__(self):
    return 'Employee_data %r' % self.oracle_id,self.name
```

I only need to get the name and O_Id

Is there anything i miss here?

Comment: are you missing "name" as a attribute in your form control, please post the html form here so that we can better recognize the error here

Comment: Added my simple HTML form above

Comment: why is action parameter blank here ?

Comment: I got what i want. your help was massive. but when i incorporate a database query returns an empty list. updated the code above.

Comment: you gotta debug it buddy try to send hardcode value first if that works  Employee_data.query.filter_by(team = 1001).all()

Comment: yes i did hardcode and it returns an empty list on my consul

Comment: then its the database problem buddy how is Employee_data class designed can you post it here

Comment: I posted the Employee_data model. i dump a data to the table, does this make any problem?

Comment: team is a string try this and let me know Employee_data.query.filter_by(team = "1001").all()

Comment: Still the same.

Comment: wait can you also post the data you have in this model

Comment: just some random data for tasting. i want only the name and O_id to be displayed on a form and make some update then return it to another table.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the method to use when using GET or POST

html

```
<form method="GET" action="/search" >
    <input type="text" name="make"/>
    <input type="text" name="model"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>

<form method="POST" action="/search_post">
    <input type="text" name="make"/>
    <input type="text" name="model"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

Python

```
    # Getting arguments from a GET form
@app.route("/search")
def do_search():
    make = request.args.get('make')
    model = request.args.get('model')
    return "You search for car make: {0}, and car model: {1}".format(make, model)


# Getting arguments from a POST form
@app.route("/search_post", methods = ['POST'])
def do_post_search():
    make = request.form.get('make')
    model = request.form.get('model')
    return "You search for car make: {0}, and car model: {1}".format(make, model)
```

Comment: My login form has a **POST** method but now it return **"None"** and whenever i put it under **IF** conditional it returns **fail*